# labels right next points in gg plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Ive tried to google my way to the answere to the question, but none seems to give the answer to what im trying to do.

My goal is to add legends right besides the observations within the plot to show the name of the observation. Name of observations are  located in the first column of my data frame.

```
ggplot(data = coef.vec)+aes(x = coef.x, y = variable.mean) + 
geom_point()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use labels with `geom_text()` in next style. I have used simulated data:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
data <- data.frame(group=paste0('Obs',1:10),
                   coef.x=rnorm(10,0,1),
                   variable.mean=runif(10,0.015,0.05),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
ggplot(data,aes(x=coef.x,y=variable.mean))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label=group),hjust=-0.15)
```

Output:

[image]